# Nginx stat() Permission denied - I have reviewed other posts' answers

Tags: nginx

At error.log, there are log of stat() errors.

```
stat() "/srv/server/public/js/build/app.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

The application folder is at /home/ec2-user/server.

Here is the nginx setting:

```
location / {
    alias /srv/server/public/;
    try_files $uri @proxypass;
}
```

where **/srv/server** links to **/home/ec2-user/server**.

User 'nginx' is used at nginx.conf.

```
user  nginx;
```

I have added **nginx** to group **ec2-user**.

```
sudo gpasswd -a nginx ec2-user
```

I tried to run **sudo -u nginx stat /home/ec2-user/**, it works. But when I run **sudo -u nginx stat /home/ec2-user/server**, it says **Permission denied**.

The folder(**/home/ec2-user/server**)'s permission is **drwxrwxr-x**.

If I can't fix this error, can I disable nginx's stat() command?

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/ec2-user?

Comment: @kyle Thanks. Once I do **sudo chmod g+x /home/ec2-user**, it works. Can you post an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to stat a directory doesn't necessarily mean you have permissions to list the contents of the directory.

Every directory in the path must be accessible by nginx.

Comment: Once I do **sudo chmod g+x /home/ec2-user**, it works.